# Federated store with repositories from different server

Tags: java, sesame, allegrograph, federated

I want to create an abstract repository to a federated store in AllegroGraph.

I can connect to the repositories stored on different server. But when I try to combine them using federate function, it throws an error that it cannot find the repository on the second server.

I found the same question in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846073/allegro-graph-federate-repositories-located-on-different-server) but it doesn't help. Any hints?

This is my code:

```
AGServer server = new AGServer(SERVER_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
AGServer server2 = new AGServer(SERVER_URL2, USERNAME2, PASSWORD2);
println("Available catalogs: " + server.listCatalogs());
AGRepositoryConnection custCon = server.createRepositoryConnection("repo1", CATALOG_ID, false);
AGRepositoryConnection supCon = server2.createRepositoryConnection("repo2", CATALOG_ID, false);
AGAbstractRepository rainbowRepo = server2.federate(custCon.getRepository(), supCon.getRepository());

rainbowRepo.initialize();
AGRepositoryConnection rainbowConn = rainbowRepo.getConnection();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SailRepository` class implements `FederatedServiceResolverClient`  for the federation context, so u can use the class SailRepository to add a federated store with different repositories :

```
AGServer server = new AGServer(SERVER_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
AGServer server2 = new AGServer(SERVER_URL2, USERNAME2, PASSWORD2);

AGRepository repo1 = server.getCatalog(CATALOG_ID).openRepository("repo1");
AGRepository repo2 = server2.getCatalog(CATALOG_ID).openRepository("repo2");

Federation federation = new Federation();
federation.addMember(repo1);
federation.addMember(repo2);
federation.setReadOnly(true); 

SailRepository rainbowRepo  = new SailRepository(federation);
rainbowRepo .initialize();

SailRepositoryConnection rainbowConn  =  rainbowRepo .getConnection(); //for querying and updating the contents of the repository.
```